# in ng-repeat I need to open row <tr> when even index and close row </tr> when odd index in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a json object with more number of objects ,
I need to display in table format each row having two different objects.
in jsp i can use

```
if(index%2==0) {
    tr open tag
}

if(index%2!=0){
    tr close tag
}
```

How can i achieve this in angular js

Comment: What did you try thusfar?

Comment: I tried $odd and $even in <td>

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by using the following script....

```
smsApp.filter("myFilter", function() {

return function(input, test) {

    var newArray = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x += 2) {
        newArray.push(input[x]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
});
```

In html i did

> `<tr ng-repeat="eachDocument in AllDocument | myFilter">
>   <td>{{eachDocument.name}}</td>
>   <td>{{AllDocument[($index * 2+1)].name}}</td>
>   </tr>`